# String.format option for locale specific double formatting like Double.toString()?

Tags: java, localization, formatting, double

I would like to format my `double` in Java using `String.format()` so that I can use a `Locale` for formatting. However, I cannot find the right combination to mimick java's Double.toString().

I want the number of decimals the same as `Double.toString()`, but the rest (grouping and decimal separated) to be the localized. And I want to use the `String.format` / `Formatter` options.

This is what I would to to achieve:

```
double: 12_345.678_90 --> 12 345.6789
double: 12_345.6      --> 12 345.6
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Locale fr = Locale.FRENCH;
System.out.println(new Double( 12_345.678_90 ).toString() );
System.out.println(new Double( 12_345.6 ).toString() );

System.out.println(String.format(fr, "%,f", new Double( 12_345.678_90 ) ) );
System.out.println(String.format(fr, "%,f", new Double( 12_345.6 ) ) );

System.out.println(String.format(fr, "%,g", new Double( 12_345.678_90 ) ) );
System.out.println(String.format(fr, "%,g", new Double( 12_345.6 ) ) );
```

Output

```
12345.6789
12345.6
12 345,678900
12 345,600000
12 345,7
12 345,6
```

Comment: Kind of unclear what you want. Do you want to output the double in French locale, or the way Double.toString outputs it?

Comment: Mind if I make the code a bit shorter by removing the `Double` constructor calls? Autoboxing will handle this easily...

Comment: @JonSkeet I just left them there so it's clearly visible that the Doubles are exacly similar.

Comment: Unfortunately it introduces horizontal scrolling. Personally I'd just remove the spaces after and before each `(` and `)` but I assume that's your preferred formatting style...

Comment: Well, what if you remove all trailing 0-s in numbers where there is a decimal point?

Comment: I don't want to remove all trailing 0-s. I want the same number of decimals as `Double.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to stick with `String.format` there is no direct way to achive what you want. If you know the number of digits then you can craft the format string.

Below is are some more theoretical solutions. Both are not recommended to use and posted only just for fun of coding. ;-)

```
double d1 = 12_345.678_90;
double d2 = 12_345.6;

// toString()
System.out.println("Double.toString: " + Double.toString(d1));
System.out.println("Double.toString: " + Double.toString(d2));

// one (not recommended) solution
// using proprietary sun.misc.FloatingDecimal and reflection
Field value = FloatingDecimal.class.getDeclaredField("nDigits");
value.setAccessible(true);

int numberOfDigits = (int) value.get(new FloatingDecimal(d1));
String format = "String.format  : %,." + numberOfDigits + "g";
System.out.println(String.format(FRENCH, format, d1));

numberOfDigits = (int) value.get(new FloatingDecimal(d2));
format = "String.format  : %,." + numberOfDigits + "g";
System.out.println(String.format(FRENCH, format, d2));

// another (not recommended) solution
numberOfDigits = Double.toString(d1).replaceAll("\\.", "").length();
format = "String.format  : %,." + numberOfDigits + "g";
System.out.println(String.format(FRENCH, format, d1));
```

In your case I would personally prefer to use `DecimalFormat` as it was already suggested by @Attila.

Answer (score 1):

```
String formatWithLocale(Double value, Locale locale) {
    return DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH).format(value);
}
```

Not too much to say here, DecimalFormat is precisely for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not String.format(). That is what I was curious about.

Comment: I think String.format is for a whole lot different thing. It will never know you want to format a number, it's just a sequence of characters for it.

Comment: It has a lot of options, as it uses the `Formatter`. Maybe I should have clarifief it more?. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html